# EF and datetime in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am testing an application on server with SQL Server 2005 and I am getting the following error (the application runs fine with SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 versions).

> There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'Edm.Time(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=)' of PrimitiveType 'Time'.`

The code inside the `Controller` that might responsible for the error is ('might' because when this code is invoked the database does not exist yet and Entity Framework is supposed to generate the database)

```
var tempRegistrations = db.Registrations.Where(t => t.DateExpires < DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

The code in my `Model` responsible for the entry in question is

```
public class Registrations
{
    public int RegistrationsId { get; set; }
    // ...
    public DateTime? DateExpires { get; set; }
}
```

Both, SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012 versions had `datetime` data type (nullable as well) in the generated table. I am quite sure SQL Server 2005 has `datetime` datatype. So what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems SQL 2005 doesn't support the Time datatype, which is what it's trying to map it to. Perhaps change it on the Edm side to use
datetime?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896344.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> PrimitiveType 'Time'

Are you sure it's not trying to create a datatype of time?  2005 does not have this type.

I'm not sure if this is what you're using, but it looks like there is a difference between time and datetime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382832.aspx